# Why is the wait $pid command interrupted by any signal to the waiting process?

Tags: bash, kill, wait

I can't find any documentation that explains my observations in sufficiently enough terms. After I run the below code, I perform a `kill -SIGINT $my_pid` from a different shell. I will correctly see `#### received trap 2` the first two times. However, the `wait` command gets interrupted on each signal. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

for s in {0..64}
do
    trap "echo '#### received trap $s'" $s
done

./code &
pid=$!
my_pid=$$

wait $pid
wait $pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[3.7.6 Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals)

> When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait` builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.